# jquery font selector isn't showing non-standard fonts

Tags: jquery, css, fonts

i was using this jquery plugin here: [jQuery font selector at github](https://github.com/CD1212/jQuery-Font-Chooser) but it appears to be working with standard web fonts.  i thought that if i loaded font families in the css it would work since it was just changing the css font-family.  any idea why it won't work?

here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/thindery/YqrXt/2/

I added three unique fonts at the end of the list, but they do not show up.  i did a test div to make sure the fonts are working, and they seem to be.

Comment: Your Burnstow font at the bottom doesn't render with just normal CSS for me (I'm on Firefox 12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a fallback font, like `sans-serif`. The plugin doesn't seem to handle font entries without fallbacks. Here's [an updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/RustyTheBoyRobot/YqrXt/11/) of your jsFiddle. Note that Arial (a standard web font) doesn't show up without a fallback listed.